# Did I make a stupid mistake with JJ preflop?

Tags: pre-flop, mtt

Live MTT - blinds 1400/2800 (ante: 400) - 11 Players remain - ITM 9 players, 6 players on table

- Hero: UTG with 49500 behind, JJ raise to 8400 (3x)
- ...everyone folded...
- Villain: SB with ~90000 behind, re-raise to 21000
- BB fold
- Hero: all-in
- Villain: call with KK :(

I did not consider ITM at that moment.
What will be a better plan with JJ around 17-18 big blinds left?

fold? open-fold? or push (lets say I did not know SB with KK)?

Comment: What worse hand would you expect to call you?

Comment: @paparazzo  TT+, AK, AQs?

Comment: What are the other stacks? What exactly are the payouts?

Comment: last 9 pleayers ITM, 1st get around ~29%, 2nd get ~20%, could not remember the rest....

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the stacks of the other players and I don't know the payout structure. But I'll assume they are just normal.

You are 6 handed 18BB deep. I don't know what you are doing if you don't want to get jacks in pre-flop. I assume SB is a big stack and he is probably playing more aggressively to put pressure on you. This is an amazing spot. You aren't even on the stone bubble. A double up in this spot is huge and puts you into a position to win. Jacks is an easy all-in.

Side note. Just raise two times the big blind. You should only raise larger when you are deeper.

Comment: I am not sure the other table, but seems the Biggest chip leader is SB from my eyeball checking, I was around 3rd or 4th stack on the table, one of the players are only 3BB leave on Button of the hand mentioned, Big blind was almost with same me, but I was little more than him I guess

Comment: Okay then it is a little closer, but still an all-in.